# How to avoid jasmine error if testing the property of an undefined object

Tags: jasmine

With jasmine, when I try to test the property of an object :

```
var foo = {property1:'123'}
it('foo.property1 should be 123'', function() {
    expect(foo.property1).toEqual("123");
});
it('bar.property2 should be 456', function() {
    expect(bar.property2).toEqual("456");
});
```

If this object is undefined, I get the error : 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'property2' of undefined
and it breaks ALL my spec.

To  solve the problem I use a conditional to test if bar exists in the first place :

```
var foo = {property1:'123'}
it('foo.property1 should be 123'', function() {
    expect(foo.property1).toEqual("123");
});
it('bar.property2 should be 456', function() {
    if(!bar){
        fail("bar does not exist");
    }else{
        expect(bar.property2).toEqual("456");
    }
});
```

Is there a better and more elegant way ?

Comment: did you try expect(object).toEqual(jasmine.any(Object)); before testing for the object property?

Comment: I'm testing the similar idea : expect(object).toBeDefined(); but the problem is that the simple fact of testing the property of an undefined object make jasmine fail by itself and all other tests are skipped.

Comment: enclose in try catch ;)

Comment: Yes possible too, the advantage with fail("bar does not exist"); is that it informs me of the problem on the test results. May be it is actually more of a jasmine problem it shouldn't (if possible) just completely fails because of object undefined and just report the error on the tests result ?

Comment: but if you use expect(true).toEqual(false, 'does object not exist') on the catch section it should fail the test

Comment: Can you show me the code you are thinking about ?

Comment: `try{ expect(object.property).toEqual('something')  }catch(e){expect(true).toEqual(false); console.log('object is undefined')}` you can try that. if you don't want to use console. log but still want to have a message you'll need to create a custom matcher